# How I can get cookie value from 'js-cookie' in nuxt.js middleware?

Tags: nuxt.js, middleware, js-cookie

This is my code :

```
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  // If the user is not authenticated
  if (!store.state.auth.auth) {
    return redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

But my main problem is after refresh page my store is empty for that I want to use my cookie in middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cookie-universal-nuxt to set, get and remove cookies in both client and server side nuxt apps
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt

Comment: Do you think it makes sense to use stores with this solution?

Comment: you can get data from cookie and set in store

Answer (score 0):

I used `localStorage` for this problem.

The example code for set your login user credentials is below:

```
localStorage.setItem('CURRENT_USER', 'YOUR_LOGIN_USER_CREDENTIALS');
```

Middleware code example is below:

```
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
    // If the user is not authenticated
    const curUser = localStorage.getItem('CURRENT_USER');
    if (!curUser) {
        return redirect('/login')
    }
}
```

Comment: I try with your solution but not working in my middleware I have localStorage is not defined error 


export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  // If the user is not authenticated
  if (!localStorage.getItem('auth')) {
    return redirect('/login')
  }
}

Comment: How to solve this error :
localStorage is not defined

Comment: @AliSaghari `localStorage` is basic javascript class. And I used it in my `nuxt.js` project but I have not this error. Refer to the below link for your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433168/how-to-store-data-to-local-storage-with-nuxt-js#47433422